# Grouping the real and imaginary terms in the proof of Euler's formula using the MacLaurin series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

The MacLaurin series:
\begin{align}
\sin x&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots
\\\\
\cos x&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots
\\\\
e^z&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots
\end{align}

Substitute $z=ix$ in the last series:
\begin{align}
e^{ix}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ix)^n}{n!}=1+ix+\frac{(ix)^2}{2!}+\frac{(ix)^3}{3!}+\cdots
\\\\
&=1+ix-\frac{x^2}{2!}-i\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+i\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots
\\\\
&=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots +i\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots\right)
\\\\
&=\cos x+i\sin x
\end{align}
My question is how do we group $1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$ and $+i\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots\right)$ or how do we apply the fact that if a series is absolutely convergent, then every rearrangement of
the series converges to the same sum? It seems like $1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots +i\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots\right)$ corresponds to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the confusion. You can define $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ to be $x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$ and $1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$, respectively, and they converge for all $x$. If two sums converge, then you can add them together.

Comment: @Accelerator Direct addition yields $(1+x)+(-\frac{x^2}{2}-i\frac{x^3}{3!})+\cdots$, not exactly the same as the original series. So there should be some justification about it. Grouping is not something always possible, as we can see from the counterexample $1-1+1-1+\cdots = (1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots = 0+0+\cdots = 0$.

Comment: An absolutely convergent series can be summed in whatever order you want. The value of the series doesn't get affected by that order. Both the series of sine and cosine are absolutely convergent. And the series $1-1+1-1+ \cdots$ diverges; it does not equal $0$. @Riemann

Comment: Okay, but the OP is asking `how we can apply the fact that series are absolutely convergent?'. So we need to be more rigorous. And decomposing the sum as $\cos x+i\sin x$ is not actually a rearrangement of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(n)}$ for a bijection $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't know what that bijection function has to do with anything. The OP did apply the fact that if a series converges absolutely, then every rearrangement of it converges to the same sum by rearranging the terms of $e^{ix}$. I'm not sure what kind of rigor there needs to be. @Riemann

Comment: @Accelerator The most standard result about absolute convergence and rearrangement is the following theorem: if a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely and has sum $L$, then for any bijection $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{\sigma(n)} = L.$$ If you are talking about other Theorem that can be applied to this kind of rearrange(that first sums infinitely many terms then add another series), I presume that the result is not really standard or well-known. I think you need to provide reference to the theorem(and its proof) you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = L$, then so is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n=L$ for $b_n = a_{n/2}$ if $n$ is even, and $0$ if $n$ is odd. This is because $$\sum_{n=1}^{2N}b_n = \sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}b_n = \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n\to L$$ as $N\to\infty$. Hence from the convergence of series for cosine and sines, we have \begin{align*}&\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots\right)+i\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots\right) \\ &= \left(1+0-\frac{x^2}{2}+0+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)+\left(0+ix+0-\frac{ix^3}{3!}+0+\frac{ix^5}{5!}+\cdots\right)\\ &= 1+ix-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{ix^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{ix^5}{5!}+\cdots\\ &= e^{ix}\end{align*} by just summing two series like $\sum(a_n+b_n) = \sum a_n+\sum b_n$.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What is the point of writing $+0$ for the two series? And how does $\sum_{n=1}^{2N}b_n = \sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}b_n$?

Comment: The point is that we can simply add two series to get the series of $e^{ix}$, by inserting zeros. Two partial sums are the same since $b_{2n+1} = 0$.

Comment: I just found a proposition (Proposition 4.17 in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/intro_analysis.pdf). I think your argument is similar to that? So grouping the real and imaginary terms in $e^{ix}$ does not have anything to do with rearrangements!

Comment: Yes. It can be deduced without absolute convergence and rearrangement.